# A measure of variability/dispersion that captures only one direction of change

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, coefficient-of-variation, dispersion, variability

I am conducting a study trying to **correlate changes in a biologic parameter (e.g., blood bilirubin concentration) with clinical outcomes (e.g., bleeding)**.

I have found that variability in such parameter over time appraised with standard deviation (SD) and coefficient of variation (CV) correlates strongly with events.

However, I am afraid that positive changes (i.e. increases) are clinically relevant, whereas decreases not. Unfortunately, I believe that SD and CV are directionally uninformative.

Is there a **measure of variability/dispersion that captures direction of change, or that computes only change in one direction?**

A potential solution could be to discard/censor decreases… but I am afraid this could be inappropriate.

Comment: Do you mean correlation?

Comment: There are many such measures. One adopted in some financial and risk assessment communities is called the "semivariance:" you just average the squared deviations above the mean.  But it's not evident that anything like this would actually be useful for your study: how do you propose to apply this concept?  For *descriptive statistics* it's fine, but how do you hope it might work for any kind of modeling or analysis?

Comment: @whuber The key point is that, for instance, increase in parameter X is bad, whereas decreases are good... I am afraid that considering variability in both directions will dilute the actual association and possible mechanistic link... Another approach could be to generate a delta (second measurement-first measurement, putting it equal 0 if  </=0)... However, I am afraid this could be not a validated method...

Comment: @Dave I want to test the association between variability in measurements and clinical outcomes...

Comment: I understand.  But that fact need not necessarily affect how you analyze the data.  It's difficult to formulate a specific answer to such a vague, general question.  In particular, we would need to know what kind of analysis you are trying to perform.

Comment: @whuber My fault... Basically it's a survival analysis (Cox) including event and time to event, and testing the unadjusted and multivariable adjusted association between the variability parameter and the outcome

Comment: Again, that begs the question: perhaps you would be best served by conducting *the most accurate, unbiased possible analysis* and drawing conclusions from that.  It's not clear whether or why you might need some modification to give more weight to the adverse data.  Certainly that's a possible approach--I'm just saying you haven't provided any information to suggest such weighting would be a good approach and you don't tell us anything that could give clues about *how* to do such a weighting, were it even advisable.

Comment: What do you understand by dispersion or variability of the scores in a given series? Brief the different measures of variability?

Answer (score -1):

If you are concerned with a measure of variability / dispersion that **captures the direction** of change, then potentially standardizing your data can be of use.

Standardizing (also sometimes called z-transform) converts your data samples into z-scores. Z-scores, unlike standard deviation, can be negative or positive. A negative z-score, say $-2$, indicates the sample is two standard deviations below the mean. Vice versa, a z-score = $2$ indicates the sample is two standard deviations above the mean.

Thus, by standardizing your data, you now have z-scores which is a measure of variability **and** captures the direction of that variability (in terms of negative and positive z-scores).

The formula for standardization is:

$z_i = \frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{s}$

where

$z_i$ = z-score of sample $i$

$x_i$ = original data point

$\bar{x}$ = sample mean

$\sigma$ = standard deviation of the sample

Also, here is a [link](https://www.statisticshowto.com/standardized-values-examples/) with a few examples.

Comment: How does this actually help?  Standardization is just a change of units of measure.  It doesn't emphasize positive or negative deviations.

Comment: If one standardizes the data before modeling, then the parameters can be interpreted as a change in deviation of $X$ is correlated with a change in deviation in $Y$. Then, it could be that the parameters are negative or positive, hence indicating a positive or negative change in deviation.

Comment: Or you could just calculate the correlation without explicitly standardizing. What you've written here, in conjunction with calculating covariance of the standardized variables (which is the same as correlation of the unstandardized variables), is not false, but I fail to see how this on its own is pertinent.